# I want my SlideToggle() Slow or add the Time

Tags: jquery

Hello I want my animate SlideToggle() it slide up and slow or I can put the time, when I click the link please help. please See Code Below. I try to put the .slideToggle("slow") but dont' work.

```
$(function() {
    $('#bottom_menu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        animateSlider(this.hash);
    });


    function animateSlider(hash) {
        if (!$('#container div.open').length) {
            if (hash == '#about') {
                openPopup(hash);
            }
            if (hash == '#contact') {
                openPopup(hash);
            }
        } else {
            if (hash == '#about') {
                openAndClose(hash)
            }
            if (hash == '#contact') {
                openAndClose(hash)
            }
        }
    }



    function openPopup(hash) {
        $(hash + '_popup').slideToggle().addClass('open');
    }



    function openAndClose(hash) {
        if ($(hash + '_popup').hasClass('open')) {
            $($(hash + '_popup')).slideToggle().removeClass();
        } else {
            $('#container div.open').slideToggle().removeClass();
            $(hash + '_popup').slideToggle().addClass('open');
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Are you saying it does slide but not at the speed you want, or it doesn't slide at all?

Comment: it slide but I can't put the speed, I want slide up smooth and slow.

Comment: what is your `open` css class? can you also show it?

Comment: I use this code from here: http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/web-development/configure-jquerys-slidetoggle-to-slide-up-from-the-bottom/

Comment: it work but I want animate more slow not fast like the original

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(hash + '_popup').slideToggle("slow", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(hash + '_popup').slideToggle().toggleClass('open');
```